# AjaxFileUpload adding OnClientUploadCompleteAll breaks layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="afuPhotosUpload" runat="server"
    AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"
    OnUploadComplete="afuPhotosUpload_UploadComplete" />
```

This works completely fine but as soon as I add `OnClientUploadCompleteAll` like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="afuPhotosUpload" runat="server"
    AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"
    OnUploadComplete="afuPhotosUpload_UploadComplete"
    OnClientUploadCompleteAll='__doPostBack("HiddenButton", "");' />
```

The layout of the the control freaks out and becomes almost unusable.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass it a javascript function name only.

```
OnClientUploadCompleteAll="UploadCompleteFunctionName"
```

For whatever reason, they decided to treat it in same way as declaring the server-side function to execute.